# How can I fix the issue where 'Sexo invalido' is returned in my if statement even when correctly inputting 'Masculino' or 'Feminino'?

Tags: python, string, if-statement

the code returns every time 'Sexo invalido' even when i write masculino or feminino! Why?

```py
import sys

a1 = input (str('Digite o seu nome '))

a2 = input (str('Sexo: '))

if a2 != 'Masculino' or a2 != 'Feminino':
    sys.exit('Sexo invalido')

a3 = input (int('Quantos anos você tem: '))
```

Comment: Because any string is either unequal to 'Masculino' or unequal to 'Feminino'.

Comment: Why are you converting something that's already a string to a string?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the word `or` in your `if` statement

```
if a2 != 'Masculino' or a2 != 'Feminino'
```

Your `if` has two conditions:

- `a2` being different than 'Masculino'
- `a2` being different than 'Feminino'

As you used `or` between these two conditions, it will accuse 'Sexo Inválido' if any of them occur.

But do you agree with me on, if a person is Masculine, she is not Feminine? So, even if a2 is different than 'Masculino', it will activate the second condition, because **a2 is different than 'Feminino'**.

The solution for this is to change the word `or` to `and`, since it needs to be 'Sexo Inválido' just if it is neither Masculino neither Feminino

```
if a2 != 'Masculino' and a2 != 'Feminino': sys.exit('Sexo invalido')
```

I hope it works for you! Abraços e boa sorte!

Comment: Another way to think on this problem:
To be considered a correct gender, it needs to be Masculine or Feminine, so:
if a2 == 'Masculino' or a2 == 'Feminino': -> correct input
so to be incorrect, just negate everything:
if not( a2 == 'Masculino' or a2 == 'Feminino' ): -> incorrect input

Think first on the right input, than negate everything and you get the condition for the wrong input